# Typescript: Strict Checks Against "Any"

Tags: typescript, types, any, tsconfig

My Typescript configuration is allowing the following code to compile:

```
const thing : any = 123
const name : string = thing
```

Clearly, `name` is not actually a `string`, but the fact that I declare it as `any` makes my typechecker ignore it.

---

How can I configure my `tsconfig.json` to **give me an error until I provide the correct types** for my object?

**My current configuration:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*",
                "src/types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"

    ]
}
```

Comment: There is a config option, "--noImplicitAny" which might do what you want.  Seems like the closest of the available tsconfig options:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: I have updated the question with my current `tsconfig.json`. That setting is already enabled.

Comment: @oooyaya If I were to remove the `: Request` from my function's parameter list, then `noImplicitAny` would throw an error.

Comment: Hm.  Maybe you can't then.  You can cast the properties, and it'll blow up on you if their shape does not match the casting.  So like `name: <WhateverTypeNameShouldBe>req.body.name`.  You can also do something like `(<Request>req).body.name` if you only care about one of the pieces type.

Comment: @oooyaya thank you for your suggestions. I haveupdated the question with a simpler example of the problem I am having. Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanNHG You cannot get an error. That is the whole point of `any`. It disables **all** type checking.

Comment: @Saravana Thanks! I did not know that `any` was that powerful. Now all of my functions can be called without the proper values, leading to runtime exceptions and potential server crashes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the fact that I declare it as any makes my typechecker ignore it.

This is by design. By saying its `any` you are *explicitly* asking the type checker to ignore it, and that is what it does

Answer (score 1):

The type `any` disables the type checker by design. As of TypeScript 3.0, there is another type called `unknown` which is basically a strict version of `any`.

```
const thing: unknown = 123;
const name: string = thing; // <- error TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

You can find more about it in the [release notes of TypeScript 3.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type).
For now – about two years after release –, the type is not yet listed as one of the [basic types on the website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html). However, there is a [beta for a new version of the website](https://www.staging-typescript.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#unknown) which also lists `unknown`.